# Moving from Drupal to Wordpress

Tags: drupal, wordpress

I am moving my organization's website over from Drupal 7 to Wordpress, and along with that I need to connect our existing CiviCRM install with the new Wordpress install. I just have a few concerns before I start anything:

Can I just install CiviCRM for WP and hook it up to the existing database? Is there a special procedure that I will need to go through to connect our existing database with WP? Is there any risk to the data moving over this way?

Thanks!

Comment: One thing that's missing here is the users from Drupal. Although the answer above claims you can perform this function after clearing the uf table... It fails because the import of data to a different database yields an error and it's related to switching to different server and user of the database too. It (admin/users/convert contacts to CMS) only converted 2 existing users. It didn't import 4500 more. And this is of course big deal for the migration. I'm going to try another test later with the plugin tool mentioned which says it'll import everything while changing needed references. The pa

Comment: This question hasn't been answered in months. I've avoided this migration because tests weren't successful. The main problem is getting the users and other Drupal info. The admin for Drupal isn't the same name as WordPress. That could be part of the answer. I'm just wondering if it's necessary to even do it. Mainly because the domain also is changing in my case which implies some added conflicts. Update: This is civicrm 4.7.22 and the WordPress site is informational not same functions. The drupal site has over 5000 users which I need. And doing the CMS build function after truncating uf-match

Comment: What Lesley says above is exactly why

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Migrating from Drupal/Civi to Wordpress/Civi is relatively painless.  You'll need to truncate your `civicrm_uf_match` database table, which links Civi records to CMS users, and repopulate it - **Administer menu > Users and Settings > Sync Users to Contacts** works well if you want ALL your Wordpress users to be linked up.

That said, there are numerous gotchas to watch out for - I've started <strike>[compiling a list here](https://hq.palantetech.coop/projects/commons/wiki/Migrating_CiviCRM_to_a_new_site)</strike>.
UPDATE: I've merged this with documentation on wiki.civicrm.org.  Please check [Moving from Drupal to Wordpress](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Migrating+from+Drupal+to+WordPress).

Since StackExchange prefers direct text to links, here's what I've got so far:

- PayPal IPNs needed changing. You can only change future IPNs in Paypal; you may also need to set up a 307 redirect from the old URL.
- URLs linking to contribution pages etc. in mailing templates, scheduled reminders etc. need to be changed.
- Images in mailing templates and scheduled reminders must get a new absolute URL (or a redirect).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jon! Just in case anyone else is wondering about this, a warning: WP CiviCRM install will overwrite your existing database with a blank one if you connect it to your existing CiviCRM database. So make sure you have a backup copy and just connect WP to your existing database after the installation.

Comment: One more question: I did a fresh Civi install in WP and then switched the database over to the old Civi db that I used with Drupal. The main URL for CiviCRM is not the URL that drupal was using for Civi rather than the one for Wordpress. Do I have to manually update the URL for CiviCRM to read from?

Comment: @osarusan That should really be its own separate question - this info is going to be hard for future searchers to find.  Still - clear your cache, check your Resource URLs and directories, and make sure the correct base URL is set in `civicrm.settings.php`.

Answer (score 1):

I migrated a client's installation from Drupal 5 and CiviCRM 1.9. Although the original post is almost three years old at this point, it might still be useful to reply for the benefit of future searchers.

Migrating to WordPress is not simply a matter of installing CiviCRM for WordPress and hooking up the legacy Drupal database. There are several components to be aware of before you proceed:

1. Many Drupal installations include other content aside from the CiviCRM database. If this is the case with your site, you should migrate your standard Drupal content first. I have general [Drupal to WordPress migration guide](https://anothercoffee.net/drupal-to-wordpress-migration-guide/) for anyone who needs to do this.
2. Most migration procedures have a way of exporting Drupal users over to the WordPress installation. While you can migrate the users in the form of usernames and other metadata, your existing users will very likely still have to reset their accounts. This is because WordPress uses a different password hashing method to Drupal. Further, different Drupal versions use different hashing methods. Other replies mention experiencing problems with users and I suspect this might have something to do with it.
3. Finally, there's CiviCRM itself. Jon G's [Switching CMS platforms](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-cms/) guide was useful here. We had a lot of fiddling around to correct the resource URLs and menus.

We sort of got things working well enough but the user reset issue was a deal-breaker for the client. In the end, she decided to switch to a completely different CRM platform  which had a different set of migration issues!

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate easily from Drupal 7 to WordPress with the tool [FG Drupal to WordPress](https://www.fredericgilles.net/fg-drupal-to-wordpress/). https://www.fredericgilles.net/fg-drupal-to-wordpress/
But about the CiviCRM data, I don't know if it will still be compatible when you move from Drupal to WordPress.

Answer (score -4):

I would say that generally people almost always switch to Drupal, not away to WordPress. It would be hard to imagine a reason to go the other way... Drupal offers more features and flexibility and more useful integration into CiviCRM. Make sure this is really what you want to do for the long haul before putting in all the effort to switch.

Comment: Drupal has been nothing but a headache for our organization. Slow, buggy, and a pain to upgrade. Not to mention constant criticial security updates that have to be manually applied every single time. The extra "features" that Drupal offers are buggy, unfinished modules that break down as often as they work. The move to WP has been a long time coming for us.

Comment: A big reason one might move to Wordpress is that Drupal is more work to maintain for a business whose staff are not developers, who have little experience with maintaining software and adminstering modules. As Osarusan has mentioned, over time the 'cruft' has accumulated, and now there are many modules that have overlapping functionality and varying quality

Comment: I think the main point here is that the OP is not asking for opinions of whether Drupal or WP is a better solution, and hence am down voting the answer.