# I've inherited old CiviCRM data from a Drupal install - how do I get upgraded and running in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, drupal, upgrade

I am running Wordpress 4.2.1, with CiviCRM 4.5.6. Everything works for my fresh install of CiviCRM.

Now, I am chair of a political organization, and I got the old data for my county from an ex-member who ran CiviCRM under Drupal, but I don't know what version of CiviCRM he used a few years back (I think it was around 2011).  I have imported the data into mysql as dbname "civicrm_original" and the current running config is "civicrm".

I tried to swap out the data connection string to use the "civicrm_original" database then ran the command:
`http://<your_wordpress_home>wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1`

but then CiviCRM wouldn't run and it had errors like crazy, like fields not in tables and other tables not existing. So now i switched back the dataconnection to "civicrm" and we are running again, just not with all the old data.

1) how can I find out what version that database was?
2) how can I update the imported database to work with my current config?

I would be willing to update to the latest version of CiviCRM if need be.  or, would it be easier to copy the data over to the new database? I know the contacts table has new fields that aren't in my "original" db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the move from Drupal to WP I wouldn't try what your going to do, our approach would normally be to setup a fresh install of CiviCRM on the WP site. Then move over the relevant tables from the old CiviCRM into the new one. Theres a wiki page which explains the process.

[Moving CiviCRM](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location)

Comment: yea, it looks like that is the best option.   actually, i dont need much from the old database other than contacts, so i may just copy the data over only.   thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4):

If you look in the database, check the `civicrm_domain` table and see if there is a value in the `version` field. (If there is more than one record in this table, you are dealing with a multi-site).

Just guessing, but one problem you may run into is that the original database wasn't on Wordpress. Do you know what CMS it was running on?

(e.g. [Drupal upgrades](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Drupal+7) support all the way back to v2.2, but [Wordpress upgrades](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrade+WordPress+Sites+to+4.5) start with v4.1.)

So one approach would be to set up Drupal on a development server, upgrade CiviCRM on this Drupal installation, and then [move the updated CiviCRM database to Wordpress as outlined in this StackExchange Q&A](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4997/moving-from-drupal-to-wordpress).

Comment: looks like it is 3.1.1.

Comment: That's an old one. Updating the answer with further questions.

Comment: oh..yea, didn't think about that...i believe the original version was drupal.

Comment: so i think my best option is to just copy the data via sql to the new table, and make sure and copy it with the columns that are in the new schema.

Comment: Or set up Drupal on a dev server, upgrade the data, then migrate it to Wordpress?

Comment: funny you mention that.  i do happen to have a drupal instance on that server.   i assume the data structure is identical on any cms platform?

Comment: Yes, updating the answer again. :)