# Rebuild Drupal Civi from scratch in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, drupal, contacts, database, import

My situation is I have an Individual database of 11,344 Contacts in Drupal Civi, and I want to turn them all into WP Users. I know I can convert Users into Contacts, but I want to do it the other way around. I have pointed my WordPress CiViCRM to a drupal Civi database which I need very much. I used CiviCRM WordPress Profile Sync plugin to sync CiViCRM users to WordPress users. 
My request now is that I want to be able to build the old CiviCRM system by importing the data step by step. The reason I want to do that is as I was trying to create a new paid event and set the fees; the fee settings refuses to save and I tried it over and over. If the fee is not saved, registration doesn’t work. The system has been there for a couple of years now.
Mysql contact table is showing 17000 rows whilst contacts in CiviCRM is showing about 11344 contacts, I'm wondering which one to import. The is a difference between the mysql contact table and CiViCRM contacts there. I want to be able to import everything without loosing any data.  I'm planning on copying the mysql contat table of Drupal straight to my new Wordpress Civicrm database. Is that a good idea? Can you please help me?

Comment: And also, when When restoring the drupal CiVi database to the Wordpress CiVi database, it changed the order of some my menu items. the most remarkable one is the EXTENSIONS menu.

Comment: The extensions menu item now moved to : **Administer-->Customize data and screens--> Extensions** . I think there's something unusual with the old system.

Answer (score 1):

Importing contact and its details involves more efforts unless you don't want historical data of the contact like contribution, event registration, activity etc. Would suggest to use the same database for your wordpress and clear CiviCRM cache.

The menu items position may differ based on how old is your CiviCRM compared to newly fresh installed CiviCRM but you can update the position through UI if you want to move to some where else or hide it.

There is a good post that may help you to migrate from drupal to wp.
[Moving from Drupal to Wordpress](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4997/moving-from-drupal-to-wordpress)

Comment: my civi is 4.7.27. I am using the same thing for WP to avoid issues but still. The issue is that it is the same version but immediately you point to the old database issues start.

Comment: Of course I want the users' historical data and everything back. I don't have to loose anything. So, what do I do now?

Comment: So you need to use old db unless you have budget or time to export and import everything from old civi to new civi. Have updated my answer how you can migrate and what settings you need to update to have it working.

Comment: Thank you. I have read that post. It was useful for me but doesn't solve all the issues.

Comment: For instance; not being able to set event fees...

Comment: You will need to see CiviCRM error log to find more details if it has recorded any error

Comment: yes. cron not running error

Comment: You will need to setup cron job to run civi schedule jobs https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/

Comment: OK. Thanks. Do I need to do that right now as I'm focusing on the import and the stability of the data. I'm don't have scheduled jobs yet. Need the data to do that

Comment: Nope can be done when you go live

Comment: What are some of the resources do I need to import data step by step? I can dedicate the time for that if it will help me get a successful working system without issues. what are some of the resources do I need?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your main reason for rebuilding from scratch is a problem with event fees.  As Pradeep says, trying to import all your history is a lot of effort.  You are probably better debugging the events problem, or getting someone else to debug it for you.