# Trying to migrate data from Drupal 7 to new install on Drupal 9

Tags: drupal-8, migration, drupal-9

Isn't it possible to just copy tables of contacts, groups, mailings and their related data into the new install? I'm trying to figure out which tables contain essential data on contacts, activities, donations, etc. vs the ones that contain information on the site setup (like the civicrm_menu table, which I definitely want to leave behind, as somewhere over the years it got corrupted during an upgrade and has double entries and lacks a few entries as well).

Would this at all be a valid approach?

Comment: It's a hard question to answer definitively. It's valid but might require some trial and error. If it's just the menu that might work out ok.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds a bit dicey, but fortunately I think there's a simpler solution.

My answer on [migrating CiviCRM to WordPress](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/4998/12) is generic for moving CiviCRM to ANY new CMS - even the same CMS on a different site.

I would fix the `civicrm_menu` issue separately.  You should be able to restore a copy from a fresh install, then disable/re-enable any extension, which will re-add any "managed entity" entries - in practical terms, those added by extensions.